# Create diagram of JSP relationships

Tags: jsp

I am working in a fairly large Java EE code base that uses Struts and JSPs for most of the controller and view functionality. A lot of our JSPs and tag files have nested references, such as:

```
outerFile.jsp includes innerFile1.jsp includes someTag.tag includes target.tag
someOtherFile.jsp includes innerFile2.jsp includes someTag.tag includes target.tag
```

This situation could arise where target.tag is nested inside many files, so that it may be within 10 or more files. So, editing the contents of that file could adversely effect any number of parent files. I could search all of the parent files until I get to the "outermost" JSP, but that can be time consuming when I will be doing a lot of refactoring. Is there a tool available for finding these references from a known starting point (e.g. target.tag)? I already searched Google, but I may not have been using the right terminology here, so any suggestions about what this kind of tool would be called would be helpful, too.

Essentially, I am trying to reverse engineer the JSP relationships, similar to creating an Entity Relationship Diagram for Classes, but with JSP files and tags that have "parents" and "children", through <%@include %> calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try using the [IntelliJ IDEA IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), that has A LOT of JSP features more than Eclipse.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jsp_editor.html

My 2 cents,

hope that helps

P.S: I don't envy you... :(

Comment: I was trying to find a tool independent of an IDE. I appreciate your answer, though. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590000/jsp-pages-hierarchy